# How to track page view with Firebase Analytics in a web, single page app?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-analytics, single-page-application, firebase-analytics

I am trying to track simple events and pages/views through Firebase analytics.

I have a progressive web app, (SPA). It's a fullscreen game and it is not using browser history.

I am a bit confused by Google's docs to be honest, sometimes they only explain how it works in ios/Android and not in web. Also, Firebase analytics are different than the "normal Google analytics".

Firebase analytics API hasn't much:

```
analytics().logEvent()
analytics().setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled()
analytics().setCurrentScreen()
analytics().setUserId()
analytics().setUserProperties()
```

While the "Google Analytics docs" do have a [section about SPA's](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications) I haven't found how to do the same with Firebase analytics, such as manually sending page views that would be like:

```
ga('set', 'page', '/new-page.html');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

I have tried to use `setCurrentScreen` but it does nothing.
Help appreciated.

Answer (score 19):

I also wasn't able to find one place with all this information, so here is how I got it to work.

## Import

If you are using `npm`, Make sure to import the analytics:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/analytics";
const analytics = firebase.analytics;
```

Analytics automatically come with the latest Firebase SDK.

## Configure

Make sure that "Google Analytics" is enabled in Firebase Project Settings (Integrations tab). Also, make sure that Firebase Config has `measurmentId: "ID_HERE"` specified in the code - this value can also be found in Firebase Project Settings (General tab).

## Use

```
analytics().setCurrentScreen(window.location.pathname) // sets `screen_name` parameter
analytics().logEvent('screen_view') // log event with `screen_name` parameter attached
```

## Other Info

The `"page_view"` event seems to be logged automatically by default. I don't know why, but you can use the count of that event to track how many people reload/visit the app.

**Relevant Links:**

- [Firebase Screen View Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews)
- [Firebase Analytics Library Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.analytics.Analytics)
- [Google Guidance for Single Page Apps](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications)
- [Firebase Analytics NPM Reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/analytics)

---

#### Logging Using React Router

React is quite common, so I'll also list my solution for logging using it. Place the `<AnalyticsComponent />` between `<BrowserRouter>` declaration.

```
const logCurrentPage = () => {
  analytics().setCurrentScreen(window.location.pathname)
  analytics().logEvent('screen_view')
};

const AnalyticsComponent = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  useEffect(() => {
    logCurrentPage(); // log the first page visit
    history.listen(() => {
      logCurrentPage();
    });
  }, [history]);
  return (<div></div>);
};
```

Comment: Came across this while trying to fix broken firebase analytics, neat. Is there a reason why you didn't return null insetad of empty div?

Comment: `setCurrentScreen` has been deprecated. See response below instead

Comment: Browser Doesn't cancel all the calls after location change?

Answer (score 10):

Calling `setCurrentScreen` doesn't log any events on its own yet. Instead, according to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews#manually_track_screens), it adds a `firebase_screen` parameter to subsequent events.

In my SPA/PWA however, I track screen views by logging a separate `screen_view` event:

```
const handleHashChange = async () => {
    const hash = document.location.hash;

    firebase.analytics().logEvent('screen_view', { screen_name: hash.substring(1) });
}

handleHashChange();
window.addEventListener("hashchange", handleHashChange);
```

Comment: I see. So in Firebase, there are just "events" and little more? For some reasons, my events don't show up in the dashboard.

Comment: How do you track time spent on a screen? @Kev