# Why does not the data come to FirebaseAnalytics?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

After updating the application, the data does not come to FirebaseAnalytics,
those that are **Automatically collected events** https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9234069?hl=en The libraries associated with Firebase remained the same, the file and the project too (in the studio it says Connected), and the connection is the same, but the data stopped arriving (there were none custom events). It seems that something is interfering with sending data from the application to Firebase. I tried to debug the line `mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this)` To see what is inside mFirebaseAnalytics, but there is a lot of information that it is not clear where to look. Are there ways to programmatically find out if data is being sent to Firebase? Or maybe someone came across a similar thing, what else can it be, please tell me which way to dig !?

Answer (score 0):

Are you developping a single page app? Firebase analytics take some time to show events.
Read it: [How to track page view with Firebase Analytics in a web, single page app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59330467/how-to-track-page-view-with-firebase-analytics-in-a-web-single-page-app)

Comment: I know how to send custom event, but I do not need them, my problem is that Automatically collected events don't come, which should come by default